# Python - How to get the value (that is a list) of a dictionary that is inside a list?

Tags: list, dictionary

So I have a list, that includes dictionaries. Each dictionary contains three key-value-pairs. For example: **questions = [{text: 'How are you today?', answers: ['good', 'bad', 'okay'], correct: ['good', 'okay']}]**. As you can see, some values are a list.

I want to print the values like this: 
**good
bad
okay**

And I am not quite sure how to do it. I've tried to do it like this: 
"""**all_answers = [d['answers'] for d in questions]** """ and it says that 'all_answers' is a list, but it's not working to print it out with a for-loop

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list containing a dictionary containing lists for values. The following is a few examples of how you could extract the `'answers'` from this type of data structure:

```
questions = [ { 'text': 'How are you today?', 'answers': ['good', 'bad', 'okay'], 'correct': ['good', 'okay']}]

# show as a list
answer_list = questions[0][ 'answers' ]
print( answer_list )

# show as a single string joined by a space between words
answer_list = questions[0][ 'answers' ]
joined_answer_string = " ".join( answer_list )
print( joined_answer_string )

# loop through the answers and print them out
answer_list = questions[0][ 'answers' ]
for answer in answer_list:
    print( answer )
```

The reason why you need to call `questions[0]` is because the dict is inside a list. So we call the first item in the list, which gives a dict. Then, the `['answers']` grabs the `['good', 'bad', 'okay']` from the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Is `questions` always going to contain just one item? If so, you can access it by index with something like this:

```
>>> " ".join(questions[0]["answers"])
'good bad okay'
```

If `questions` is an unknown length then you need to iterate over it (there's probably a one-liner for this but it would be kinda ugly):

```
for i in questions:
    if i.get("answers"):
        print(" ".join(i["answers"])
```